# How does .(type) work in go

Tags: go, assertion, typechecking

```
func test(value interface{}) {
    if res, ok := value.(string); ok {
        fmt.Println(res)
    }
}
```

how can go confirm the type of value?
I did't find anything in struct can represent type.
Please help.

Comment: I don't understand your question. But start by taking the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/), in particular the section on [type assertions](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15)

Comment: Is your question about "how go internally does type assertion"?

Comment: in the "Tour of Go" said : if T is not an interface type, x.(T) asserts that the dynamic type of x is identical to the type T. In this case, T must implement the (interface) type of x;
but when the program running, x is just some data, how can we know which interface x is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Under the covers, interfaces are implemented as two elements, a type and a value. The value, called the interface's dynamic value, is an arbitrary concrete value and the type is that of the value. For the int value 3, an interface value contains, schematically, (int, 3).

for example:

```
s:="123"
test(s)
```

you can think of `value` as `(string, "123")`.
so when you do `res, ok:=value.(string)`, it can find out `res` and `ok`.

Comment: thanks for you answer. so the value it self has some flag represent type?
what if I use a map[string]interface{} as parameter?

Comment: thanks for you helping, I finally find the answer in [link](https://research.swtch.com/interfaces), it introduce the memory struct of interface{}